# Convert frequency to java.time.Period type

Tags: java, enums, java-time, period

I am getting frequency in form of enum i.e. [ DAILY, WEEKLY, BI-WEEKLY, MONTHLY, BI-MONTHLY, ANNUALLY] and we need to convert that enum to frequency of java.time.Period type then how to convert BI-WEEKLY & BI-MONTHLY into java.time.Period.

Comment: so you are able to convert DAILY, WEEKLY,  MONTHLY and ANNUALLY, but not BI-WEEKLY and BI-MONTHLY ?

Comment: No i am not able to convert any of enum. But i want to convert and I mention these two because is on High priority.

Comment: `if (DAILY) return Period.ofDays(1)`? for bi-weekly/bi-monthly you have to find a compromise because a period is of fixed length in whole days or weeks and bi-weekly can't be represented exactly and bi-monthly depends on the length of the month. Either this works for you or don't use `Period`

Comment: @AbhinayKumar please edit your question and add the code of your enum.

Additionally: can you edit the code of that enum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We should just be able to put static values in the enum...`Period.ofDays(1)` = daily, `Period.ofWeeks(2)` = bi-weekly, etc.
Duration unit = months, duration = 5(assume), then `Period.ofMonths(duration)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Period.ofMonths(2)` and `Period.ofWeeks(2)` for bi-monthly and bi-weekly respectively.

Comment: Thanks @Codebender and also want to add frequency with today date for starting scheduler.Please suggest

Comment: Do you know what you will be using for scheduler, @AbhinayKumar?